# How to read multiple files to plot on one line graph in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multiple-file-upload

I want to to read in multiple files and plot all the information on one graph in D3.

I've tried using promise.all but it seems to convert the files into objects which I cant iterate through.

```
Promise.all([
    d3.csv('FortunaSighted.csv'),
    d3.csv('atlasblind.csv')
])
    .then(([sight, blind]) =>  {
        console.log(sight[0][0])}
```

it just says it's undefined.

Comment: it returns arrays of objects, not 2-d arrays, with keys named after the headers. log just the `sight[0]`

Comment: Could you add what the csv's look like to your post? My guess is that sight is an array of objects thus `sight[0][key in sight[0]` would probably be fine. csvs are converted to an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

You should read in the CSV files independently and append them together, then draw them onto the single graph.

If the CSV files share a unique identifier (which they should if you're trying to plot them onto a single graph), then read them in with

```
var data1 = d3.csvParse(csv1);
var data2 = d3.csvParse(csv2);
```

The csvParse will bring them in as arrays. Now you can match the ID's up using something similar to, but not exactly:

```
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  var obj = data2.find(function(e) {
    return d.id === e.id
  });
});
```

Comment: I dont think this option works if there are n files. How would I use this method if I had n files?